# SQL Bulk Insert CSV

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I have a csv comma separated file containing hundreds of thousands of records in the following format:

```
3212790556,1,0.000000,,0
3212790557,2,0.000000,,0
```

Now using the SQL Server Import Flat file method works just dandy. I can edit the sql so that the table name and column names are something meaningful. Plus I also edit the data type from the default varchar(50) to int or decimal. This all works fine and sql import is able to import successfully.

However I am unable to do this same task using the Bulk Insert Query which is as follows:

```
BULK
INSERT temp1
FROM 'c:\filename.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

This query returns the following 3 errors which I have no idea how to resolve:

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 5. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

The purpose of my application is that there are multiple csv files in a folder that all need to go up in a single table so that I can query for sum of values. At the moment I was thinking of writing a program in C# that will execute the BULK insert in a loop (according for the number of files) and then return back with my results. I am guessing I dont need to write a code and that I can just write a script that does all of this - any one can guide me to the right path :)

Many thanks.

Edit: just added

```
ERRORFILE = 'C:\error.log'
```

to the query and I am getting 5221 rows inserted. Some times its 5222 some times its 5222 but it just fails beyond this point. Dont know whats the issue??? The CSV is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

SOB. WTF!!!

I cant believe that replacing \n with "0x0A" in the ROWTERMINATOR worked!!! I mean seriously. I just tried it and it worked. WTF moment!! Totally.

However what is a bit interesting is that the SQL Import wizard too only about 10 something seconds to import. The import query took well over a minute. Any guesses??

Comment: Don't know for sure, but it looks like a bug to me. MS may not have tested specifying `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'` since \n is the default. I'll bet it would work if you took the ROWTERMINATOR clause out. As for the performance difference, What happens if you add a BATCHSIZE clause? I'm sure the import wizard uses one.